# Extracting the corresponding value of a rank vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, vector, ranking

I intend to assign ranks to indices of an array (not the array itself) and create a second vector containing these ranks.

Example:

```
data: x=[ 3 7 2 0 5 2]
ranks: x'=[ 3 5 2 1 4 2]
```

After assigning the ranks to the indices, I need to extract the corresponding value of the `kth` (starting from 1) minimum index in each iteration of a loop, until a certain condition satisfies.

For example, I need the corresponding value of the first minimum index in the first iteration, meaning the corresponding value of element "1" in ranks vector, which equals the element "0" in the x vector, while the index of both vectors remain constant (to be clear, each element in the x vector represents a certain property of a user, so if indices change, I'll lose track of the users).

Following this procedure, in the second loop, without considering the first minimum, I need to extract the second minimum element and so on.

Comment: `[~,ind] = sort(ranks); out = x(ind);`.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question has been asked and answered on many occasions, but I can't seem to find a good duplicate.

Regardless, you would use the second output of `sort` on the `rank` vector to give you the position of where each value would appear in the sorted result.  Specifically, for each value in the second output of `sort`, it would tell you *which value in the original vector you would have to grab* to place it in this corresponding position to sort the data.

You would then use this ordering to index into your data to get the right and desired ordering.

Specifically:

```
x=[ 3 7 2 0 5 2];
ranks = [3 5 2 1 4 2];

[~,ind] = sort(ranks);
out = x(ind);
```

We get for `out`:

```
out =

     0     2     2     3     5     7
```

You can verify that we are pulling out values in the data that respect the sorted order seen in `ranks`.