# How can I locate the element of an array that is nearest to some number?

Tags: arrays, matlab, absolute-value

I have an array `A`, e.g.

```
A = [-79.0732  -82.1919  -85.0432  -87.0406  -90.0102  -92.6745]
```

and some number `x` (e.g. `-90`), and I want to find the index of the element in the array that is closest (in absolute value) to `x`.

In my example, the element closest element of `A` to `x` is `-90.0102`, i.e. the 5th element of array `A`. How can I, in general, compute the index of the element that is nearest to `x`?

Comment: @rayreng Apologies. I should have checked for dupes first.

Comment: @Jubobs - No problem :)  Sometimes it's faster to answer than find a duplicate... such as this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992090/extracting-the-corresponding-value-of-a-rank-vector-in-matlab/31992458#31992458 - we've seen **many** questions like this, but can't nail a good enough duplicate.  If I was in your situation, I would have also answered if I didn't know that there was a suitable duplicate.  FWIW, I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` is the value of interest and `A` is the array, run

```
[~, inearest] = min(abs(A - x));
```

Then `inearest` will contain the index of the element of array `A` that is closest to `x` (in absolute value).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
[~, i] = min(abs(A - (-90)));
```

This will take the difference of each element in `A` with the number you supply.  `min` will then find the minimum, and return the index of it.

Comment: Yes, this works if I add abs. So if it turns into:

[~, i] = min(abs(A - (-90))); 

the first part returns the value (which is not needed) and the i return the position.
Thanks

Comment: @Matt After your edit, the main text of your answer no longer matches the code: absolute value `~=` difference.